# Drawing Rectangle around base candles

Tags: pine-script, stock, trading, tradingview-api

I have written a code for RBR pattern. In this at the end, i want to draw a rectangle around base candles. But getting an error. Below is my script:

```
//@version=4
study("RBR Pattern", overlay=true)

rally_body_pct = 75
base_body_pct = 50
max_candles = 6

// Define the base candle
base = close > open and abs(close - open)/(high - low) * 100 <= base_body_pct

// Define the rally candle
rally = close > open and abs(close - open)/(high - low) * 100 >= rally_body_pct

// Check if RBR pattern is formed
rbr = false
for i = 0 to max_candles
if rally[i] and base[i+1] and rally[i+2]
    rbr := true
    break
**
// Draw rectangle
if rbr and bar_index <= max_candles
bh = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", high[1])
bl = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", low[1])
hline1 = hline(bh, color=color.green, linewidth=3)
hline2 = hline(bl, color=color.green, linewidth=3)
fill(hline1, hline2, color=color.green, transp=0)**

plot(close)
```

Getting error in Draw rectangle code. `Cannot call 'hline' with 'price'=series[float]. The argument should be of type: input float;`

Comment: What programming language is this? Please edit your question and add it to tags.

Comment: Tradingview pine script

Answer (score 0):

You can't use hline with a serie float, only with float.
And in pinescript, you can't modify a serie float to a float.

You should use Pinescript V5 and the use :

```
line.new(x1, y1, x2, y2, xloc, extend, color, style, width) → series line
```

which is able to handle serie float.